# Where are the cookies created on client's computer

Tags: php, cookies, location

When we use php **`setcookie()`** function, where are they created on client's computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **[`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)**, an HTTP-header (Set-Cookie) is included, containing information about the cookie to be set, its expiration etc.

Where that cookie itself is stored is **upto the browser**.

The browser then sends the cookie's content, which it stored *somewhere*, with the `Cookie:` header **when appropriate**, as described below.

> There are two headers, Set-Cookie and Cookie,
>   that are related to cookies. The Set-Cookie header is sent by the
>   server in response to an HTTP request, which is used to create a
>   cookie on the user's system. The Cookie header is included by the
>   client application with an HTTP request sent to a server, if there is
>   a cookie that has a matching domain and path.

**[RFC6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt)** defines the *HTTP Cookie* and *Set-Cookie* header fields.

Comment: Like he said, it's up to the browser, and you should not care (besides curiosity ofcourse ;)), as you should not edit cookies outside of the browser

Comment: If cookies are handled in a different manner for every browser, is there any way to access them from some console application programmatically in client's computer?

Comment: @user1439090 Reliably handling it for **every** browser won't be possible. If you pick a *single* browser, you could check the browser's documentation for the place where it stores cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The browser receives the HTTP response with the `Set-Cookie` header and then handles it internally.

It might store the cookie in memory, in a file of cookies, in a file in a directory of cookies, or anything else it likes. It is an implementation detail that is entirely transparent to the web server.

Most browsers will provide a UI to view the existing cookies.

You can also use a request monitoring tool (either one built into the browser, or an external one like Charles Proxy) to watch the cookie headers being sent back to the server in requests.